# Extract update repository from .deb file

Tags: software-installation, repository

I recently installed zoom on my ubuntu 20.10.by mistake i deleted its update repository using softwere and updates.how can i get the repository back without reinstalling to the softwere. is it possible extract that update repository from zoom.deb installer file.?

Answer (score 1):

.deb files simply are archives.

Try to extract it using your favorite GUI archiver which should detect the archive type.

From commandline use the file command to see what type it is. For these I tested it's xz files. Not sure if that's the only valid archive format for .deb or if there are others.

Comment: i was able to extract the ,deb file..........i tried searching various files in it for the repository link but found none.

Comment: Just had a look into the one I downloaded (not sure if it's the same file), it seems like it doesn't contain any etc/apt/sources.list.d/somename.list file. So I guess it sets the repo when you run the program (perhaps first run) or something else. But what's the problem with reinstalling btw.?